# Validation rules for checkbox: how to display elsewhere?

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation, error-handling

As shown in this image the error message for checkbox is messed up. How can I display this somewhere else, only for the checkbox field?

[image: Checkbox error message messedup]

Here is the bit of code I used.

```
$(function() {  
$("#reservation").validate({    
    rules: {
        "room[]": {
            required: true
          },
        start: "required",
        end: "required",
        name: "required",
        phone: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 14
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        address: "required"
    },        
    messages: {
        "room[]": {
            required: "Please select a room <br/>"
          },
        start: "Select date in ROOM AVAILABILITY",
        end: "Select date in ROOM AVAILABILITY",
        name: "Enter your full name",
        phone: {
        required: "Phone number is required",
        digits: "This is not a numeric value",
        minlength: "Number is too short",
        maxlength: "Number is too long"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        address: "Address is required"
    },              
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

});

And my checkbox fields are:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="'.$id.'"> $name.$desc
```

Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to your question is actually in the plugin Validate ({}); itself.

The rule is set in there, unfortunately I don't think you change it therefore I suggest you move the check box to right hand side of to the name.

for example

```html
1. <input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="'.$id.'"> Delux for 1 Person<br/><br/>

Becomes <br/><br/>

1. Delux for 1 Person <input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="'.$id.'">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes i did that but but i was thinking maybe there is some other way to display the return errors.

Comment: Hi I am  not sure  if there is another way, let see if another member I will come up with alternative.